# Calling controller method with Ajax in ASP.NET Core 3.0 is causing a 500 error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application and I want to call a controller Method with a jQuery AJAX request.

I've set a breakpoint on `return response`. The strange thing is that this breakpoint is reached, so the method returns a value. However in the Chrome console I always get a 500 error. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
var postValue = {
  swLat: mapBounds._sw.lat,
  swLng: mapBounds._sw.lng,
  neLat: mapBounds._ne.lat,
  neLng: mapBounds._ne.lng,
  withRoutes: true
};

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(postValue);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/getNodes",
  data: jsonString,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  failure: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public JObject getNodes([FromBody] MapBounds value) 
{
  dynamic response = new JObject();
  response.nodes = "none";
  response.status = "ok";
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Enable verbose error messages and check what the actual cause of the 500 is in the response.

Comment: What exactly does the 500 error say?

Comment: Also note that `$.ajax()` has no `failure` property in its settings. You either need to use `error` or attach a `fail()` handler.

Comment: I was able to find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58072703/jsonresultobject-causes-the-collection-type-newtonsoft-json-linq-jtoken-is.